# Completeness calculation: Where does the $\sum_{i = 0}^n g(i)$ in $E_p[g(T)] = \sum_{i = 0}^n g(i) {n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$ come from?

Tags: binomial-distribution, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

I have the following definition of completeness:

> **Definition**
> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be an i.i.d. $f_\theta (y)$, where $\theta \in \Theta$. A statistic $T(\mathbf{Y})$ is complete if no function $g(T)$ exists (except for $g(T) \equiv 0$) such that $E_{\theta}[g(T)] = 0$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$. In other words, if $E_\theta [g(T)] = 0$ for all $\theta \in \Theta$, then necessarily $g(T) \equiv 0$.

The completeness theorem is given as follows:

> **Theorem**
> Assume the existence of a minimal sufficient statistic. If a sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf{Y})$ is complete, then it is minimal sufficient.

An example is given as follows:

> **Example**
> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be an i.i.d. $B(1, p)$, and so $T(\mathbf{Y} = \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \sim B(n, p)$. We have $T = T(\mathbf{Y})$
> $$E_p[g(T)] = \sum_{i = 0}^n g(i) {n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$$
> for $0 < p < 1$. We can see here that $T(\mathbf{Y}$ is a minimal sufficient statistic.

I understand that ${n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$ is the binomial PDF, but I don't understand where the $\sum_{i = 0}^n g(i)$ part is coming from.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expected_value_and_variance) for the binomial distribution says that the expected value of a binomial random variable $X \sim B(n, p)$ is $E[X] = np$. I know this isn't the same thing as above, but I don't see where $E_p[g(T)] = \sum_{i = 0}^n g(i) {n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$ comes from. Where does the $\sum_{i = 0}^n g(i)$ in $E_p[g(T)] = \sum_{i = 0}^n g(i) {n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}$ come from?

Comment: That equation applies the definition of expectation: it is the sum of possible values ($g(i)$) multiplied by their chances of occurring ($\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$).

Comment: @whuber Got it. Thanks!

Comment: This is also sometimes called [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1500751/14893).

Comment: This is presumably not the issue but the expectation should be written$$E_p[g(T)] = \sum_{i = 0}^n \left\{ g(i) {n\choose{i}} p^i (1 - p)^{n - i}\right\}$$

Comment: @Xi'an The braces are superfluous, because the argument of the summation extends *at least* to the rightmost appearance of its formal variable $i.$

Comment: @whuber: I was just trying to make sense of the $\sum_{i=0}^n g(i)$ question.